# I18n in NextJs the Key is displayed before the translation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I am developing a system with Nextjs and react, I handle the translations with I18next, I handle the translations through Json I establish the key and the translation, the components I want to translate I import const { t } = useTranslation('indexts' ); and I establish the translation, example {`${t('TitleVerify')}`} everything works correctly except for one detail, when I change the language for a few thousandths of a second the TitleVerify key is displayed before the translation, I have tried to solve the problem and review the documentation and I have not found anything. If you could tell me where the problem may reside or how to approach it to solve it, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

I have tried multiple ways and have not found any solution to the problem.